# How to call SOAP service from phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How to call SOAP service from phonegap application with/without using additional library ?
should work on all os's ( atleast android, IOS)

Examples can be more appreciated.

my input to the service will be look like this

```
<Parm>
    <ProcessID>105</ProcessID>
    <attrname>attrValue</attrname>
</Parm>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get away with building the XML manually and posting it to the SOAP end point. You need to generate the expected SOAP body, but it in a SOAP message and just POST it to the end point. You'll need to know which version of SOAP is expected, what the message request looks like and what the message response looks like.

You can handle the XML side however you want. There's no right answer for that (aside from not parsing the raw XML with string methods), whatever you're comfortable with using.

Comment: my input to the service will be look like this <Parm><ProcessID>105</ProcessID><attrname>9912345678</attrname></Parm>

Comment: I should able give the method name and URL and soap action & namespace if allowed to call the service along with the input data. If you can refer any example link can be great help,